# How to detect inline replies in Discord?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot and would like it to be able to determine if a message is an inline reply.
I have looked through the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-reference-object) regarding inline replies/message references and have tried a few things. However I have not been able to figure out a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Its best to include some more details such as code snippets to attract more experts to provide a solution for you. Please review How To Ask topic in help.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?